# GeoJSON layer is not visibile on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to add the GeoJSON to the map on Leaflet

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "contour_communes.geojson",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                geojsonLayerWells.addData(data);
                console.log(data)
            });
        }
        }).error(function() {console.log('erreur geojson')});

        geojson_layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {  

    layer.setStyle({fillColor :'blue'}) 

});

geojsonLayerWells.addTo(mymap);
```

but the layer is not showing on the map. Any idea?

exemple of a feature from the geojsonfile

````
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "communes_last",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 461, "insee_comm": "02042", "nom_commun": "AZY-SUR-MARNE" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 371907.61918287910521, 6275053.340028743259609 ], [ 372036.291736110404599, 6275133.823878624476492 ], [ 372036.230170833470766, 6275119.570710268802941 ], [ 372035.928191001003142, 6275089.622116575948894 ], [ 372035.528258231759537, 6275036.995363153517246 ], [ 372035.340574892878067, 6274993.543284893967211 ], [ 372034.921209115767851, 6274936.416128330864012 ], [ 371966.947272408462595, 6274945.020814280956984 ], [ 371900.008886745141353, 6274953.62049803417176 ], [ 371897.261963931727223, 6274957.094747267663479 ], [ 371897.498650426452514, 6274971.981879002414644 ], [ 371900.001680019078776, 6274992.052782591432333 ], [ 371905.010754124785308, 6275032.88718868046999 ], [ 371906.434155185648706, 6275042.748838956467807 ], [ 371907.61918287910521, 6275053.340028743259609 ] ] ], [ [ [ 373393.210992991458625, 6276123.821156785823405 ], [ 374034.200834281975403, 6276921.605571278370917 ], [ 374109.993985108332708, 6276879.270939180627465 ], [ 374142.007709467085078, 6276857.306635057553649 ], [ 374196.117390273138881, 6276834.548235200345516 ], [ 374244.020882009819616, 6276813.89593933802098 ], [ 374246.261377746413928, 6276813.019868864677846 ], [ 374276.578909289150033, 6276797.816038311459124 ], [ 374313.753174892975949, 6276771.845031293109059 ], [ 374330.790745071251877, 6276759.818978087045252 ], [ 374345.749342846160289, 6276746.244110056199133 ], [ 374360.678532869496848, 6276726.26272027567029 ], [ 374386.502288563060574, 6276672.466466556303203 ], [ 374416.967313924280461, 6276614.320273972116411 ], [ 374422.098221540218219, 6276603.734411896206439 ], [ 374430.070146294601727, 6276610.277318624779582 ], [ 374433.204011533234734, 6276615.976813580840826 ], [ 374434.584386824921239, 6276615.79728835914284 ], [ 374514.544096583209466, 6276583.221713749691844 ], [ 374544.011497062863782, 6276571.13797393720597 ], [ 374573.824107075692154, 6276559.052551437169313 ], [ 374589.16079698264366, 6276552.748089022934437 ], [ 374611.391284299956169, 6276543.814393405802548 ], [ 374622.764280178584158, 6276539.086608270183206 ], [ 374637.926657739561051, 6276532.436585241928697 ], [ 374664.809650035575032, 6276521.576542722992599 ], [ 374667.91005336336093, 6276520.00380415096879 ], [ 374672.90874381136382, 6276518.249098104424775 ], [ 374675.683849047694821, 6276521.006585536524653 ], [ 374679.334975093428511, 6276526.530383843928576 ], [ 374685.887467264255974, 6276524.76844990439713 ], [ 374699.337732562504243, 6276521.242963360622525 ], [ 374726.410875152680092, 6276514.191129519604146 ], [ 374765.551430370775051, 6276503.273775695823133 ], [ 374804.520849321968853, 6276492.703353982418776 ], [ 374861.420207442890387, 6276476.681527484208345 ], [ 374928.321398752741516, 6276458.188546299934387 ], [ 374972.977973539149389, 6276445.513073583133519 ], [ 374999.877215807442553, 6276438.288119771517813 ], [ 375032.296943909546826, 6276430.171484984457493 ], [ 375014.800447240355425, 6276380.387270805425942 ], [ 375012.559331503289286, 6276381.090352742932737 ], [ 374992.171672468539327, 6276340.669749520719051 ], [ 375002.268002353492193, 6276321.403375016525388 ], [ 375020.241214152832981, 6276288.248583330772817 ], [ 375025.925422669912223, 6276285.451644198969007 ], [ 375029.528271267598029, 6276280.586726791225374 ], [ 375028.097143106453586, 6276269.858507523313165 ], [ 375024.075623217271641, 6276258.969294789247215 ], [ 375044.963357241475023, 6276258.525115165859461 ], [ 375057.194105054833926, 6276252.754033394157887 ], [ 375183.030379768577404, 6276211.474426261149347 ], [ 375171.69984337920323, 6276151.274247669614851 ], [ 375233.100289383495692, 6276138.519129499793053 ], [ 375217.69921325170435, 6276057.042461900040507 ], [ 375319.890351138019469, 6276054.656265079043806 ], [ 375370.237808956531808, 6276077.965550701133907 ], [ 375371.267070674861316, 6276095.235090886242688 ], [ 375655.358399097400252, 6275805.480343820527196 ], [ 375794.608457287191413, 6275709.341197880916297 ], [ 375786.334534263878595, 6275685.220971060916781 ], [ 375788.184151575027499, 6275674.824199188500643 ], [ 375790.365053391258698, 6275661.482612621039152 ], [ 375786.46949488070095, 6275640.898514776490629 ], [ 375732.742138575878926, 6275559.783257661387324 ], [ 375668.388236830593087, 6275458.11673117056489 ], [ 375656.562217240629252, 6275439.648318434134126 ], [ 375652.560770152951591, 6275433.088504314422607 ], [ 375649.953412247705273, 6275429.292101546190679 ], [ 375644.561168459593318, 6275420.661378893069923 ], [ 375629.257431971491314, 6275396.842613297514617 ], [ 375618.828096846700646, 6275381.65704164840281 ], [ 375605.446235198294744, 6275362.67673671618104 ], [ 375602.141889637161512, 6275357.498653049580753 ], [ 375599.187697368266527, 6275353.35766363888979 ], [ 375596.580386028683279, 6275349.561279123649001 ], [ 375591.715100598114077, 6275342.83248226903379 ], [ 375582.512224101345055, 6275331.449896609410644 ], [ 375551.961022831208538, 6275295.584885844029486 ], [ 375539.990609186817892, 6275283.003577402792871 ], [ 375516.404100934334565, 6275259.743651252239943 ], [ 375487.784032068273518, 6275230.621370580047369 ], [ 375417.891233662958257, 6275198.058841142803431 ], [ 375387.288956223288551, 6275187.816174931824207 ], [ 375337.5237100936356, 6275177.144538952037692 ], [ 375322.861737716302741, 6275179.464341819286346 ], [ 375309.92187852866482, 6275180.910382777452469 ], [ 375237.984712061879691, 6275190.771237989887595 ], [ 375160.355828788189683, 6275201.697009364143014 ], [ 375159.177435890131164, 6275208.108102712780237 ], [ 375157.703157257870771, 6275225.081116830930114 ], [ 375156.525568356912117, 6275231.665346525609493 ], [ 375155.174549430317711, 6275238.077272400259972 ], [ 375128.733890933624934, 6275231.795937768183649 ], [ 375117.499099106877111, 6275228.732480057515204 ], [ 375112.682737489289138, 6275232.390691735781729 ], [ 375108.017172363353893, 6275231.373856137506664 ], [ 375104.365506096393801, 6275225.67792329005897 ], [ 375082.930868464522064, 6275219.372957076877356 ], [ 375054.021197462745477, 6275201.84999271761626 ], [ 375023.4386841202504, 6275195.760909278877079 ], [ 375014.798087833623867, 6275193.72391471080482 ], [ 375011.169877024367452, 6275193.048418404534459 ], [ 374988.706927676219493, 6275188.306166622787714 ], [ 374974.887799533840735, 6275186.29337559454143 ], [ 374958.985181735595688, 6275181.693470566533506 ], [ 374926.496764802897815, 6275174.054876696318388 ], [ 374878.034346049011219, 6275146.408598080277443 ], [ 374814.86288469057763, 6275110.867138945497572 ], [ 374794.619407323771156, 6275100.747335773892701 ], [ 374785.819970427604858, 6275101.653935019858181 ], [ 374780.488897218601778, 6275106.006793469190598 ], [ 374775.586414610676002, 6275128.362277531065047 ], [ 374775.10303001862485, 6275135.808758347295225 ], [ 374763.880503411521204, 6275135.341649401932955 ], [ 374723.305839599866886, 6275133.452999785542488 ], [ 374677.034026087319944, 6275131.417510945349932 ], [ 374656.653208711126354, 6275128.915349072776735 ], [ 374655.473660027026199, 6275135.153204115107656 ], [ 374620.745647649979219, 6275128.389525578357279 ], [ 374619.916897691204213, 6275135.837599526159465 ], [ 374614.953949484101031, 6275182.603599355556071 ], [ 374607.871015310869552, 6275181.424594231881201 ], [ 374603.102147608704399, 6275232.864262391813099 ], [ 374589.116003893257584, 6275232.063492407090962 ], [ 374589.161471459781751, 6275354.289353722706437 ], [ 374589.015979143790901, 6275360.176312134601176 ], [ 374546.697362638136838, 6275354.659231220372021 ], [ 374526.467177020444069, 6275347.481605947948992 ], [ 374493.959418690181337, 6275335.686339747160673 ], [ 374486.004516932182014, 6275332.606867237016559 ], [ 374480.676339176134206, 6275337.652144349180162 ], [ 374478.604884185944684, 6275337.661721285432577 ], [ 374478.413960788340773, 6275333.680715900845826 ], [ 374463.541494526318274, 6275327.863194877281785 ], [ 374430.858887478127144, 6275315.549153982661664 ], [ 374390.394947255903389, 6275300.327785030007362 ], [ 374382.785354515654035, 6275297.24663847964257 ], [ 374380.032158955000341, 6275299.163709535263479 ], [ 374383.250120268319733, 6275360.954653289169073 ], [ 374378.590127764560748, 6275361.149271340109408 ], [ 374333.547751774487551, 6275363.953771366737783 ], [ 374342.810406913456973, 6275539.462706225924194 ], [ 374342.656816045229789, 6275543.61852369364351 ], [ 374344.148063100874424, 6275567.676701451651752 ], [ 374177.791311170498375, 6275580.387649769894779 ], [ 374187.08388309692964, 6275649.597399909049273 ], [ 374190.894327568705194, 6275652.350016636773944 ], [ 374192.126424177957233, 6275657.538314022123814 ], [ 374163.156580524402671, 6275664.596527382731438 ], [ 374125.046881983929779, 6275673.774126929230988 ], [ 374122.655333154427353, 6275679.325316727161407 ], [ 374139.056154452438932, 6275755.255524314008653 ], [ 374134.052267238614149, 6275755.79786403849721 ], [ 373953.44586937193526, 6275786.749198349192739 ], [ 373854.777455754519906, 6275803.992936966940761 ], [ 373855.769895236939192, 6275832.555683122947812 ], [ 373856.888741106085945, 6275850.902941288426518 ], [ 373859.189370134612545, 6275863.358237725682557 ], [ 373871.72370639781002, 6275924.591455661691725 ], [ 373886.910461685911287, 6275999.664063380099833 ], [ 373889.116960725863464, 6276029.43387888930738 ], [ 373893.790650847833604, 6276032.182810087688267 ], [ 373894.332869999867398, 6276037.547653555870056 ], [ 373890.898992334143259, 6276041.718641518615186 ], [ 373891.275633625336923, 6276048.64250008482486 ], [ 373883.684388485155068, 6276049.715920338407159 ], [ 373589.189786223636474, 6276094.16430907510221 ], [ 373477.207910404365975, 6276107.828612858429551 ], [ 373469.825672636099625, 6276117.038349548354745 ], [ 373450.848056440823711, 6276119.894133505411446 ], [ 373450.148202350595966, 6276117.819597787223756 ], [ 373402.004275503277313, 6276122.884335730224848 ], [ 373393.210992991458625, 6276123.821156785823405 ] ] ] ] } }```
````

Comment: With the info you provided in your question: no idea. What do you see in the console? Any errors? How does data look like in the console? And you are setting feature styles outside `success` function, so this will very likely fail.

Comment: I have features properties in console , wich mean I have features with success, but it is invisible. is ther any idea to verifi if the problem is a coordinate system problem

Comment: You see your GeoJSON and know your CRS settings, but there is no info about that in the question.

Comment: Go to http://geojson.io  to check your GeoJSON file itself. Look at the coordinates, Long should be less then 181 and Lat less than 91. Beyond that I've post some Leaflet stuff at http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/ for a class, it may help.

Comment: @Namoat can you please add more info and a sample of the geojson file.

Comment: @Mapperz  I edited the question and gave example from my geojson file. The coordinates values seem to be wrong but I am not sur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GeoJSON is in projected coordinates, so you have to unproject it to CRS EPSG3857. This can be done with `L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject` method in `coordsToLatLng` option of GeoJSON layer creation with `L.geoJSON`.

In your case this would look something like this:

```
var geojsonLayerWells = L.geoJSON(null, {
  style: function(layer) {
    return {fillColor :'blue'};
  },
  coordsToLatLng: function(coords) {
    var point = L.point(coords[0], coords[1]);
    var latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(point);
    return latLng;
  }
});

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "contour_communes.geojson",
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
        geojsonLayerWells.addData(data);
        console.log(data)
    });
    geojsonLayerWells.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(geojsonLayerWells.getBounds());
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log('erreur geojson')
  }
});
```

That's how it looks then:

[image]